# Can a broken Swordfish's bill bone regrow?

Tags: zoology, ichthyology, bone-biology

The Broadbill Swordfish (*Xiphias gladius*) is characterized by a long bill or a "sword" which is an extension of its upper lip bone. The swordfish uses its sword in fighting, including attacking hard objects, which may cause it to break. Like all bones, it can heal after being broken but can it regrow back to full length?